# about binary quadratic form

Tags: number-theory

Case1) dicriminant = -15, there are two binary reduced form : x^2+xy+4y^2 and 2a^2+ab+2b^2

there are only solution a=b=x=y=0 by using calculator

Case2) for discriminant = -32, there are two bianry reduced form
: x^2+8y^2 and 3a^2+2ab+3b^2,they have integer solution x=4,y=3,a=5,b=1

i 'm curious about condition that non-equivalent binary quadratic forms has same value like Case2).
for example, non-equivalent binary quadratic forms has same value if D == (mod 4) it's just example i think it's not condition

thank you for reading my question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.